# How to make a button go down when scrolling? (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's header. I want to make these 2 buttons go down with Joblist text when I scroll down.

[image]

---

It SHOULDN'T be like that.  I mean these 2 buttons need to stay below the logo always. and when I scroll down, logo and buttons should go down and disappear.

[image]

```
<header>
  <div class="header-btn">
      <a href="" class="btn-one"> Button 1 </a>
      <a href="" class="btn-two" style="float: right;"> Button2 </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

css

```
header > .header-btn > a {  /* Header buttons styling */
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
color: #f6f6f6;
background-color: rgba(77,85,106,0.8);
letter-spacing: .1em;
padding: 1em 2em;
border-radius: 30px;
border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
position: absolute;
top: 65%;
margin: 0 15px;
font-family: 'Syncopate', sans-serif;
```

}

forgot to mention that Im using js for how fast or slow that Joblist text disappears.

```
var pContainerHeight = $('header').height();
 $(window).scroll(function(){
 var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (wScroll <= pContainerHeight) {

   $('.logo').css({
  'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /4 +'%)'
});
```

}

Comment: Use position fixed. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: @ElDanielo `fixed` position means they won't scroll at all.

Comment: We need to see more of your code, preferably in a working snippet. It's probably the `position: absolute` that's your problem, I assume `.header-btn` is not positioned relative, therefor your absolute positioning isn't working as expected. But I can't say more than that without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make those buttons go down with Javascript. Simply add an event listener on the page scroll (as you already do) and, as the user scrolls, add the difference on the position of those two buttons.

Something [like this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fz6y6twc/) should work:

```
var original_top = $(".buttons").offset().top
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".buttons").offset({top: $(this).scrollTop() + original_top})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting header position:relative and .header-btn position:absolute. The relative position will scroll and the absolute is in relation to its relative container so it will also scroll.

Comment: Opps missed the comment from DBS sorry.

Answer (score 0):

change position to relative from absolute